# Why are my CPT not showing next and previous links on single post view?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type

Wondering of someone can help here!

I have a function that gets the next/previous link for posts and it is included inside the template for every post type as a global nav to and from posts. Here is the code for it:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_post_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous post when applicable.
 */
function theme_post_nav() {
    ?>
    <?php

    // Don't print empty markup if there's nowhere to navigate.
    $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    $next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

    if ( ! $next && ! $previous ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>

    <nav class="navigation post-navigation <?php if ( 'supporter' == get_post_type() ) { ?>supporter<?php } ?>" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'theme' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <?php
                previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( '<span class="meta-nav icon icon_arrow-backward"></span> %title', 'Previous post link', 'theme' ) );
                next_post_link(     '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',     _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav icon icon_arrow-forward"></span>', 'Next post link',     'theme' ) );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->

    <?php
}
endif;
```

This outputs the correct nav for normal posts but when it goes into a custom post type it only shows the current post its on as the link.

In my single-supporter.php I have got:

```
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

And then in the footer I have got the function to get pagination:

I wondered if there was anything glaringly obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Is your function theme_post_nav() inside the loop?

Both previous_post_link() and next_post_link() should be inside the loop to work.

More here; http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link